# Separable kernel in convolution

Tags: convolution

I came across this statement:

> When a d-dimensional kernel can be expressed as he outer product of d vectors, one vector per dimension, the kernel is called separable.

With kernel being kernel in convolution, function g:
$$f(x) = \int h(u)g(x-u)du$$
My question is, what are conditions that kernel can be expressed as outer product? I got familiar with what outer product is, but I can't find conditions. Does anyone know name of related theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues can give you some hint. However, a More direct method is to treat the 2D kernel as a 2D matrix K and to take its singular value decomposition (SVD). If only the first singular value is non-zero, the kernel is separable.