# Kernel representation as dot product.

Tags: linear-algebra, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Consider the following kernel $k(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i y_i)$. We want to represent it like $k(x,y) = \langle \phi(x), \phi(y) \rangle$, where $\phi(x)$ is vector depends only on $x$.

It differs from the polynomial kernel since we can't easily separate them. Does there any chance to separate here?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the case $n=2$.

The matrix associated to your kernel is

$$K=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

with eigenvalues $3$ and $1$, both non-zero.

Using the criteria mentionned for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2636780), we can conclude to the non-separability.

Explanation: The general entry of $K$ is $K(e_i,e_j)$ where $(e_1,e_2,\cdots e_n)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$; for example

$$K_{1,1}=K(e_1,e_1)=K((1,0),(1,0))=(1+1\times 1)(1+0\times 0)=2$$

What we have done in the case $n=2$ extends at once to the general case because $n \times n$ matrix $K$ with $K_{i,j}=1$ if $i \ne j$ except on the diagonal where $K_{i,i}=2$ has eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_1=n+1 \ \text{(multiplicity 1) and} \ \ \lambda_k=1 \ (\text{multiplicity} \  n-1)$$

Remark: We have used eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ instead of singular values $\sigma_i$ because, for real *symmetric* matrices, $\sigma_i=|\lambda_i|$ ; therefore the criteria of a single non-zero singular value is the same as a single non-zero eigenvalue.

none of them zero.

Comment: I've never seen this criteria. Actually there is Mercer theorem that shows that $k(x,y) = \langle \phi(x), \phi(y) \rangle$ iff $K$ is positive definite for all $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. Maybe they are equivalent?

Comment: No they aren't. See another [signal processing explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51520/34431)

Comment: It's very strange, since if it's true, then we can easily verify whether the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: No contradiction: here we are in finite dimension $n$, whereas Mercer's theorem deals with an infinite decomposition.

Comment: Okay, assume this is right. But then we have the same result for the polynomial kernel. $k(x,y) = (\langle x, y\rangle + 1)^2$. The corresponding matrix is $K_{i,i} = 4$, $K_{i,j} = 1$ it's eigenvalues are non-zero. But $k(x,y) = \langle \phi(X), \phi(Y) \rangle$.

Comment: With which $\phi$ ?

Comment: F.e. $\phi(x)$  is all $\sqrt{2} x_i x_j$ and $x_i^2$ and $1$. So it will be $\phi(x) = (1 , x_i^2, \sqrt{2} x_i x_j) $